# Awkward situation when trying to land the initial tech internship?

Tags: internship

A little bit of my background, I am currently a second year student in a tech major. My course has a compulsory internship in year 3. Therefore, I'm actively looking for any open position, and I found there are a lot of good internship offered now. However, I can not apply until I finish year 2 (as a international student I can not have a job during my semester unless it is an internship semester) (which is about December this year).

So my question is, Is there any thing I can do in this situation ? Or just let the opportunity pass?

Thank you for reading my question, and sorry for my English because English is not my first language (feel free to correct my question).

Comment: Why can you not apply until you finish year 2?  Is this a rule, or do you believe there is a problem with the timeline?  I would expect most companies to understand that a student interviewing for an internship would be in the middle of the current year while they are interviewing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Companies are usually aware of the conditions around foreign students. The company where I work, for example, makes clear that upon hiring an intern, additional time for preparing all the document has to be taken into account.

It might be possible that they can be flexible in the start date, so there is no harm in explaining your situation and making clear that your earliest start date is in December.

Even better, if you want to save their time, you can just contact the company and ask if the start date of the internship is flexible. Again, remember to mention your circumstances, so that it's clear for them. If they are flexible, you can apply and have the interview, if they aren't, you saved your and the interviewers' time.